# How to log errors from "Add-ADGroupMember" to textfile

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the following function:

```
function SAMACCOUNTNAME {
    foreach ($item in (Import-Csv $textBox1.Text -Delimiter ";")) {
        Write-Output $item.("User") into $item.("Group") >> $LogPath
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $item.("Group") -Member $item.("User")
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter if the user was successfully added to the group. This way the log always shows that the users "has been added".

How can I log an error, when the user can't be added (Username incorrect, etc..)?

I have to mention, that I work with Windows Forms. So I can't see the errors in the script window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect the [error output stream](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/) to a file. Use `2>>` instead of `2>` to append to the file instead of overwriting it with each iteration.

```
Add-ADGroupMember ... 2>> 'C:\error.log'
```